# Python : error tuple index out of range when plotting pandas columns X Vs Y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Dears,

happy new year 2018 from a french living in Shanghai

I'm facing an issue when trying to plot a pandas dataframe into a canvas.
The context is that I have an emmbedded graphic into a tkinter frame. So the matplotlib graphic should be in this frame (by creating a subplot)

Regarding the data, this is an SQL extraction of 4.5M rows and 45 columns that I saved into a pickle.
I'm applying some operations to reduce the size of the data in memory, then sorting and grouping, to finaly create a dataframe with the index and 3 columns DM_DESC, YEAR and SALES_W_VAT.

Important to mention that DM_DESC is a category type because I want this column to be the X Axis of the graphic, ordered according to the list (listDM in the code below).

Finally, when plotting the DM_DESC as X axis, and SALES_W_VAT as value, I got the famous error "tuple index out of range"

I read a lot of docs on this error, but I really don't understand where the problem is....

Would appreciate your help

[EDIT] : based on the first comments, I have created a small program with reproducible error.

The problem comes for the line I tried to order the colum DM_DESC according to the list listDM

```
DonneesBase["DM_DESC"]=pd.Categorical(DonneesBase["DM_DESC"],np.array(ListDM) ,ordered=True)
```

If I comment this line, there is no error, plotting is fine, but the Xaxis is not ordered as expected

Also what is interesting is that if I plot the dataframe directly with df.plot, I have no error, and the X-axis order is the expected one.

So weird

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imp ort pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ListDM = [
                'Jan Big Low price',\
                'CNY 1',\
                'CNY 2']

f=plt.figure()
a=f.add_subplot(111)
DonneesBase = pd.DataFrame({"DM_DESC":["CNY 2","Jan Big Low price","CNY 1"],"YEAR":[2017,2017,2017], "SALES_W_VAT":[2.254691e+09, 2.509911e+09,1.8e+09]})


#ORDER COMMAND USING CATEGORICAL AND ARRAY
DonneesBase["DM_DESC"]=pd.Categorical(DonneesBase["DM_DESC"],np.array(ListDM) ,ordered=True)


sales = pd.DataFrame(DonneesBase[(DonneesBase["YEAR"] ==2017)].groupby(["DM_DESC","YEAR"])["SALES_W_VAT"].sum()).reset_index(inplace=False)

# THIS FAILED WHEN USING ORDER COMMAND
a.plot(sales["DM_DESC"].values, sales["SALES_W_VAT"].values)

#THIS IS WORKING WELL EVEN WITH ORDER COMMAND...
sales.plot(x="DM_DESC", y="SALES_W_VAT")
plt.show()
```

here is the full error track

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PYTHON_PROGS\TEST\debug.py", line 24, in <module>
    a.plot(sales["DM_DESC"].values, sales["SALES_W_VAT"].values)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", 
line 1717, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1372, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", 
line 404, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(this, kwargs):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 392, in _plot_args
    ncx, ncy = x.shape[1], y.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range## Heading ##
```

Comment: What's the _full_ error traceback?

Comment: I think the error would be somewhere in your code to create the data frame. Otherwise, if the dataframe is correct, your plot code would produce good figure. Here is the reproducible dataframe. 
`sales = pd.DataFrame({"DM_DESC":["Jan Big Low price","CNY 1"],"YEAR":[2017,2017], "SALES_W_VAT":[1.254691e+09, 1.509911e+09]})
`

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm just facing the very same issue only on travis CI, while on production it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue by explicitly converting the non numerical data to a list

```
x = list(sales["DM_DESC"].values)
a.plot(x, sales["SALES_W_VAT"].values)
```

I discovered this issue when trying to run my code in a new environment with Matplotlib v3, so perhaps there is some compatibility issue that now requires explicit type conversion instead of implicit. I haven't found any specific explanation of why the code formerly worked and now does not.